# How do I get Jupyter Notebook to use the latest version of Python installed on my PC?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have python 3.10 installed on my PC but every time I open a new Jupyter Notebook and check the version it still says that I am using the previous version that I had. Is there a way to make it start using the latest version every time I open a new notebook?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, but on macos.  Turns out, my package manager `homebrew` by default installed an older JupyterLab 3.3.2, which is hardcoded for Python 3.9. However, homebrew did offer another installer option for JupyterLap 3.3.4-2, which uses Python 3.10.  So, if you still want to use the latest Python, then look for a more recent JupyterLab/Notebook version.

Answer (score 9):

You should try to work with virtual environments. They are very commonly used in Python. Then, on your Jupyter Notebook, you will be able to choose the particular environment (and Python version) you want to run your notebook.

First, create a virtual environment using Python 3.10:

```sh
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv nameofthevenv --python python3.10
source nameofthevenv/bin/activate
```

Then, inside the virtualenv:

```sh
(nameofthevenv) $ pip install jupyter ipykernel
(nameofthevenv) $ python -m ipykernel install --user --name nameofthevenv
(nameofthevenv) $ jupyter notebook
```

Finally, go to the page in your browser the last command opened, and choose the running kernel at the top right: `Kernel >> Change Kernel >> <list of kernels>`. You will see `nameofthevenv`. Select it and you're good to go: the python version will be Python 3.10.

Comment: Python virtual environments are there own little hell, starting with which one to use? virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv, Conda, and lately by-passing them all to use Docker instead.  All the Python "experts" have their favorite and can't comprehend how anyone could disagree.  It's a frustrating mess for new and occasional Python users.

Comment: ```python -m ipykernel install --user``` worked like a charm. Thanks a lot